# Integrating c++ and qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Okay I'm resetting this whole post because I guess I didn't have enough " Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example " which really is the entirety of my question, because I am just so LOST on slots and signals.. so here's 2nd attempt, I will leave out flower.cpp, but know it has a function in there

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QtQuick>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <iostream>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QObject>
#include "flower.h"



void Flower::onClicked(){
//code i've been trying to test all day
}
```

flower.h (my header for the class flower (the function))

```
#ifndef FLOWER_H
#define FLOWER_H

#include <QObject>

class Flower
{
private slots:
void onClicked();

};
#endif // FLOWER_H
```

main.cpp (this is where my app QML is started from, and I'm trying to setup the connection of signal and slot there)

```
QQuickView home;
home.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
home.show();
QObject *homePa = home.rootObject();
QObject *buttF = homePa->findChild<QObject*>("buttFObject");
QObject::connect(buttF, SIGNAL(qmlClick()), buttF,
                 SLOT(Flower.onClicked()));
```

this is the navmenu with the mousearea that I want to have the onClicked: command attached

```
Rectangle {
    signal qmlClick();

    id: navMenu
    color: "#00000000"
    radius: 0
    anchors.fill: parent
    z: 3
    visible: false
    border.width: 0
    transformOrigin: Item.Center
               MouseArea {
                id: buttFArea
                objectName: buttFObject
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: navMenu.qmlClick()
            }
           }
```

When I try to run right now I receive this error "W libAHDP.so: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::qmlClick() to (null)::Flower.onClicked()"

Apologies for my first post being very misleading and mixed up I hope this is more clear on what my issue is

Comment: *Please* provide a [mcve] - right now your question has far too much code in it that isn't relevant to the actual problem, making it much harder for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only QObjects can have slots so Flower must inherit from QObject. On the other hand you are using an approach that always brings problems that is to try to obtain a QML element from C++, instead you must export the C++ element to QML using `setContextProperty()`:

**flower.h**

```
#ifndef FLOWER_H
#define FLOWER_H

#include <QObject>

class Flower : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Flower(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_SLOT void onClicked();
};

#endif // FLOWER_H
```

**flower.cpp**

```
#include "flower.h"
#include <QDebug>

Flower::Flower(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{}
void Flower::onClicked()
{
    qDebug()<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "flower.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    Flower flower;
    QQuickView view;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("flower", &flower);
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Rectangle {
    color: "#00000000"
    anchors.fill: parent
    transformOrigin: Item.Center
    MouseArea {
        id: buttFArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: flower.onClicked()
    }
}
```

For more information I recommend reading [Best Practices for QML and Qt Quick](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-bestpractices.html)

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply I greatly appreciate it! I have implemented your fixes and receive this error now "undefined reference to 'vtable for Flower'"

Comment: @DevinB remove the build and compiled folder returned

Comment: Your awesome thank you so much for helping me through this @eyllanesc I did a clean and was able to run my app. I'm still getting and error in reference to my onclick
"W libAHDP.so: qrc:/main.qml:258: TypeError: Property 'onClicked' of object QQuickItem(0xd74786a0) is not a function"

Comment: i had a lowercase f in onClicked: flower.onClicked()

Comment: both ways I receive error  "W libAHDP.so: qrc:/main.qml:257: TypeError: Property 'onClicked' of object [object Object] is not a function"

Comment: I noticed I had a QML Item that was referenced as Flower in the QML, after I changed that I was receiving this error: "ReferenceError: flower is not defined"

Comment: @DevinB It seems that you have problems to avoid it you can find the complete project in the following link: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55176915

Comment: @DevinB According to the error message, it seems to me that you are trying to prove my solution in your project and that is not correct because your project may have other errors that I do not know, instead it tests my answer on its own, verifies that it works, understands and just at that time try to implement it in your code